# How to multi-boot <HP Probook 470 G2>

Tags: multi-boot

(I am not a native English speaker, so this question could include some errors.)

Hello guys. First, I would like to say to you thank you for reading or answering to this question.

I am a student who is interested in computer science and Unix / Linux operating system. (So I am now learning very simple and basic information about Linux operating system.)

So I wanted to multi-boot Microsoft Windows 10 (Because I am beginner so I need to get installed an easy operating system to solve problems about Linux operating system...) and Linux distribution together. But... I couldn't.

How can I install (I know how to install also.) more than 1 operating system on one hard disk and **select that what operating system I want to boot**?

I tried to multi-boot on my old computer (Dell desktop), it worked very well.
I am very confused because I don't know how to use new computer's booting system.

Who could help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you have done dual-boot in the past then for now I think you are not able to get Boot-Screen using F2 or F12 (according to your laptop) keys.

Here is the solution if you are using Windows 10. Go to PC Settings->Update and Security->Recovery. Here you will see Restart button. Hold your SHIFT key and press it.

Now when your laptop restarts you will end up with Blue screen having some option to choose from. Go to Advanced Options->Startup Settings->Restart. Now you will get option to get the boot menu.

Comment: My laptop has different shortcuts to other usual desktop computer. I entered to BIOS setup... what can I do? (I am going to try your answer. I haven't try yet.)